# Can hardware have a license?

Tags: licensing, hardware

I was reading a previously asked question, [Can I distribute related software and hardware under the same license?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/261/can-i-distribute-related-software-and-hardware-under-the-same-license), and then it occurred to me that hardware might have patents.

Does this mean that you can't release hardware under, let's say, a Creative Commons license?

Comment: Related: http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/142/how-do-open-source-concepts-apply-to-hardware

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes.**

Examples include:

- Chumby HDK<sup>1</sup>
- [The TAPR Open Hardware License](http://www.tapr.org/ohl.html)<sup>1</sup>
- The MIT License<sup>2</sup>
- Various BSD licenses<sup>2</sup>
- Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 and Creative Commons Attribution ShareAlike 3.0<sup>2</sup>
- GPL<sup>2</sup>

Note that the last four can also be used for software. None of the examples given are exclusively for hardware, with the exception of the TAPR Open Hardware License.

So you can, in fact, release hardware under a Creative Commons license!

---

<sup>1 This was given as an example [here](http://www.ladyada.net/library/openhardware/license.html), though not necessarily endorsed.</sup>

<sup>2 These were described and compared [here](http://www.inmojo.com/licenses/).</sup>