# Can you make an open source piece of hardware?

Tags: licensing, hardware

**Edited**

Say I was building a truck, and I wanted others to be able to help with the design. Assuming I applied a CC license to it. Could I release it as an open sourced truck? How would this work?

This is different because I have already released it under a CC license, that does not mean it is open sourced.

Comment: Also related: http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/312/can-hardware-have-a-license